# textField.clearButtonMode = /* whatever */ doesn't work

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uikit

I'm creating a textField and adding it to a view like this:

```
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(/*blah blah */)];
textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;

[otherView addSubview:textField];
```

The text field is rendered as expected in `otherView`, but the clear button is never rendered, no matter what value I assign to clearButton.  Anyone know what might be causing this?

Comment: do you see the clearButton when you enter text?

Comment: Actually, I just checked again, and I was wrong.  When the text field has a value, the button is there.  I guess I assumed "Always" means "Always", when it really means, "when `.text != nil`".

Comment: It makes sense. If there's no text, what do you expect to clear?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is that `UITextField.clearButtonMode` works.  When the text field has a value, the button is there. I guess I assumed "Always" means "Always", when it really means, "when `.text != nil`".

Comment: Did you really just answer your own question of 3 years ago lol?

Comment: Hehe.  Just stumbled on it and didn't want to leave it unanswered ;-)

Comment: Oh, I see you posted the answer as a comment... 3 years ago :D